# How use flexible widget to divide my screen into 2

Tags: flutter, visual-studio, android-studio, dart

I would like to divide my screen into 2 using the Flexible Widget. The first flexible widget I would like to set is 80% as yellow and blue for the remaining 20%. Is there any way of dividing it using the flexible widget as I would like to have the remaining 20% of empty space in blue colour.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("BitCoin cryptocurrency ")),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Center(
                  child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text(
                      "BitCoin cryptocurrency",
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: TextField(
                        controller: valueEditingController,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: 'Bitcoin Value',
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)))),
                  ),
                  DropdownButton(
                    itemHeight: 60,
                    value: selectLoc,
                    onChanged: (newValue) {
                      setState(() {
                        selectLoc = newValue.toString();
                      });
                    },
                    items: locList.map((selectLoc) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem(
                        child: Text(
                          selectLoc,
                        ),
                        value: selectLoc,
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: _loadWeather, child: const Text("Load Value")),
                  const SizedBox(height: 10),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                      children: [
                        FittedBox(
                          child: Text(
                            // description,
                            nu,
                            style: const TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 25),
                          ),
                        ),
                        FittedBox(
                          child: Text(
                            nu2,
                            style: const TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 25),
                          ),
                        ),
                        FittedBox(
                          child: Text(
                            nu3,
                            style: const TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 25),
                          ),
                        ),//FittedBox
                      ],
                    ),//Column
                  ),//Padding
                ],
              )),//Cloumn //Centre
            ],
          ),//Column
        )// SingleChildScrollView
        
        );//Scaffold
  }
```

Sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: Flexible Widget has a flex attribute. If you're using 2 Flexible widgets set flex equal to 8 for the yellow one and flex equal to 2 for the blue one.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using the `Flexible` widget with the `flex` attribute at flex 8 and flex 2

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Fexible widget'),
        ), //AppBar
        body: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverFillRemaining(
              hasScrollBody: false,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Flexible(
                    flex: 8,
                    fit: FlexFit.loose,
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.yellow,
                    ), //Container
                  ), //Flexible
                  Flexible(
                    flex: 2,
                    fit: FlexFit.loose,
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ), //Container
                  ) //Flexible
                  //Row
                  //Row
                ], //<Widget>[]
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ), //Scaffold

      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    ),
  ); //MaterialApp
}
```

[image]